# Как вернутся назад в метод в intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains

Проблема следующая. Смотрю код какого-то очень большого метода. Вижу много вызовов всяких методов внутри. Зажимаю ctrl и кликаю на один из них, чтоб перейти к реализации, посмотреть что внутири. Вижу, что ничего полезного для меня. Хочу вернуться назад. И приходится руками искать тот большой метод, откуда я начал свое путешествие через ctrl + клик. Есть какой-то хоткей, чтоб перейти назад, откуда я пришел?

Comment: контрол+альт+влево, если не установлены утилиты от nvidia для windows, если установлены - они переворачивают экран по этому хоткею, но это отключается в них же

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо за комментарий. Не установлены. Я на линуксе.Там немного другая проблема)) По этому хоткею переключаются воркспейсы рабочего стола) Но это мелочи) Дело вот в чем, я вроде как то таким хоткеем пользовался. Разве он просто не переключает вкладку в ide? Что если моя проблема находится в рамках одного очень большого файла? Поправьте меня пожалуйста, если я не прав и этот хоткей действительно возвращает в точку начала перехода а не просто перелистывает вкладку в ide.

Comment: этот хоткей именно переход курсора, вкладки - контрол таб

Comment: хоткей можно поменять в Settings - Keymap

Comment: Спасибо всем, я чуть позже это сделаю и отпишусь!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можете тыкнуть сверху `navigate` -> `back` - это и есть действие для хоткея (вроде как дефолтного) `alt + left`

Comment: Дааа! Вот то что мне надо!!!