# Как вернутся назад в метод в intellij idea кнопкой?

Tags: intellij-idea

Проблема следующая. Смотрю код какого-то очень большого метода. Вижу много вызовов всяких методов внутри. Зажимаю `ctrl` и кликаю на один из них, чтоб перейти к реализации, посмотреть что внутири. Вижу, что ничего полезного для меня. Хочу вернуться назад. И приходится руками искать тот большой метод, откуда я начал свое путешествие через `ctrl` + клик.

Есть вариант с хот кей `Alt` + влево / `Alt` + вправо.
Это работает и всё хорошо, спасибо за наводку сюда:

[Как вернутся назад в метод в intellij idea?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1128511/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-intellij-idea)

Но в ранних версиях IDE были на панели ещё и стрелочки для этого по умолчанию, я к ним сильно привык в своё время - как бы их вернуть?

**IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 (Community Edition)**

Answer (score 0):

Надо включить

view -> appearance -> toolbar

Появится панель:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как раз стрелочки влево/вправо